# How can we detect which keyboard is open, Numeric or Alpha Numeric in android Webview?

Tags: android, webview, android-softkeyboard

Hi i am new here i need to know how can i detect which keyboard type is open in android webview here is my try

```
KeyboardUtils.addKeyboardToggleListener(this, new KeyboardUtils.SoftKeyboardToggleListener()
        {
            @Override
            public void onToggleSoftKeyboard(boolean isVisible)
            {
                if(isVisible){
                    InputMethodManager imm =(InputMethodManager)MainActivity.this.getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
                    Log.d(TAG, "onToggleSoftKeyboard: "+imm.getCurrentInputMethodSubtype().getMode());
//                       



                }
                Log.d("keyboard", "keyboard visible: "+isVisible);
            }

        });
```

Comment: And what is the result?

Comment: i Got this log *onToggleSoftKeyboard: keyboard*

Answer (score 0):

You can use below code to check the type

```
private fun getKeyboardType(){
        val devicesIds = InputDevice.getDeviceIds()
        for (deviceId in devicesIds) {
            val device = InputDevice.getDevice(deviceId)
            device.keyboardType //returns an integer
            
            // Now compare this integer with predefined constant values : https://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/InputType
            
        }
    }
```

Compare the integer values with constants [here](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/InputType)

You can check when keyboard opens/closes using a listener.

```
val listener = object : ViewTreeObserver.OnGlobalLayoutListener {

    // Keep a reference to the last state of the keyboard

    private var lastState: Boolean = activity.isKeyboardOpen() 
    override fun onGlobalLayout() {
        val isOpen = activity.isKeyboardOpen()
        if (isOpen == lastState) {
            return
        } else {
            dispatchKeyboardEvent(isOpen)
            lastState = isOpen
        }
    }
}
```

And add that listener in activity lifecycle callback

```
override fun onResume() {
    super.onResume()
    val view = getRootView()
    view.viewTreeObserver.addOnGlobalLayoutListener(listener)
}
```

And remember to remove listener when activity is no longer active

```
override fun onPause() {
    super.onPause()
    val view = getRootView()
    view.viewTreeObserver.removeOnGlobalLayoutListener(listener)
}
```

Comment: How can i compare keyboardType with current keyboard open?

Comment: How can i get keyboardType when keyboard Open?

Comment: Thanks but I know how to check open/hide/close keyboard but my issue is how can i detect which keyboard is open numeric one or alpha numeric one

Comment: As I mentioned earlier, compare keyboardType integer with constant values that you can get details from : https://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/InputType 

Loop through and match with types and you'll know which type is on screen.

Comment: Sorry i got this not above one
 onToggleSoftKeyboard: 2
onToggleSoftKeyboard: 1
onToggleSoftKeyboard: 1
onToggleSoftKeyboard: 1

Comment: i got 4 types 2, 1, 1, 1

Comment: Okay, now compare those with the constant values from the link that I posted.

Comment: How can youplease give me a demo?

Comment: there is no change in the log what ever keyboard is open always got 2 1 1 1 so how can i determine?